# NextResult with Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper, clickhouse

I am using Dapper with ClickHouse database (https://clickhouse.yandex/). This is distributed column-oriented database. It works well, but query result can be divided into many blocks, so I should use NextResult to retrieve all data.
Sample code:

```
public static void ExecuteSQL(ClickHouseConnection connection, string sql)
{
    using (var reader = connection.CreateCommand(sql).ExecuteReader())
    {
        do
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                        ...
            }
        }
        while (reader.NextResult());
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use Dapper. In order to call NextResult I should use `QueryMultiple` method. I made the code:

```
public static void ExecuteDapperQuery<T>(ClickHouseConnection connection, string sql)
{
    Dapper.DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores = true;
    using (var dapperQuery = connection.QueryMultiple(sql))
    {
        do
        {
            var list = dapperQuery.Read<T>().ToList();
            ... /* Do something with list */
        }
        while (true);
    }
}
```

but this code throws exception `ObjectDisposedException` when all data are retrieved and SQL reader becomes null.
I need to know is there the way to know when I should finish iteration? Or is there any other way to work with that database?

Comment: What exception does it throw? You need to be more specific.

Comment: It is because of the infinite do/while loop. You can only call read for the number of statements executed.

Comment: The exception is `ObjectDisposedException` and it occurs when the reader is null. I don't know how I can check if NextResult returned true or false.

Comment: @Nkosi, I have only 1 statement. The reason of QueryMultiple is that data divided into different blocks and can't be retrieved without calling NextResult. See first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the infinite do/while loop. You can only call read for the number of statements executed.

> I need to know is there the way to know when I should finish iteration?

Check to make sure the reader has not already been consumed before reading the set

```
using (var gridReader = connection.QueryMultiple(sql)) {
    while(!gridReader.IsConsumed) { //<-- query multiple until consumed
        var list = gridReader.Read<T>().ToList();
        ... /* Do something with list */
    }
}
```